# Forfile command to delete all except a directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to use the `forfile` command to delete all .frm files in some directories. But, I don't want to delete the *.frm files under a specific directory.

I have this, but i don't know how to put the name of the dir where i don't want to delete files:

```
forfiles /p D:\myfolder\ /s /m *.frm /c "cmd /c IF NOT DESIRE_DIR del @PATH"
```

Some help, please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /ad /b^|findstr /l /v /i "Dirname1 Dirname2"') do @echo %A
```

This is also a lot quicker than `forfiles`. `Forfiles` is only really useful when listing files by date.

Put your folder names in `Dirname1`, `Dirname2` to exclude them. Spaces mean or.

Remember in a batch file `%A` becomes `%%A`.

```
forfiles /p D:\myfolder\ /s /d -7 /m *.frm /c "cmd /c echo @path >> %temp%\temp.txt"
for /f "delims=" %A in ('findstr /i /v "list of excluded directories" ^< "%temp%\temp.txt"') do echo %A
```

Your `/m` was also in the wrong place and you would have seen a message telling you that.

Comment: Well, it's a good answer, but i forgot to say, that i used the `forfiles` command with dates: `/d -7` I mean: `forfiles /p D:\myfolder\ /s /m /d -7 *.frm /c "cmd /c IF NOT DESIRE_DIR del @PATH"` To delete those files older than 7 days.